# Prove that $I-A$ is non singular

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, determinant

> If $A$ is a skew-symmetric Matrix then prove that $I-A$ is non singular, where $I$ is the identity Matrix of the order equal to that of $A$.

I know that this question can be done by using the concept of eigenvalues. But I want a solution that does not involve that. I have one solution but it is like very difficult to think.

**My approach**

We see that the matrix $(I-A)(I+A)^{-1}$ is orthogonal. Hence we can say that $\frac{\det(I-A)}{\det(I+A)}=1$ so $\det(I-A)\ne0$

This solution is nice but hard to think.

**Second approach (Solution given in book)**

Consider a homogeneous system of equation $(I-A)X=0$ $\implies AX=X$

Now, $$(AX)^{T}=X^T$$
$$\implies -X^TA=X^T$$
Now post multiplying by $X$ gives,
$$X^TX=0$$ now the book says $\implies X=0$ so $(I-A)X$ has only trivial solution. And hence $\det(I-A)\ne0$

I cannot understand how they concluded that $X$ is $0$. How did they just cancel $X^T?$

---

I want you guys to give nice solutions of this problem and if possible pls explain the last step in the second solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *“We see that the matrix $(I-A)(I+A)^{-1}$ is orthogonal.”* Wait. How do you know that $I\color{red}{+}A$ is invertible?

Comment: @user1551i didn't think of that, that $I+A$ is invertible or not....and can you pls elaborate your second comment...i cannot understand it

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad take the 2x2 matrix {0,1,0,1} for instance I+A would be {1,1,1,1} but it is singular hence $(I+A)^{-1}$ doesn't exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement in question is false if the elements of $A$ are taken from a general field. E.g. the complex matrix
$$
I_2-\pmatrix{0&i\\ -i&0}=\pmatrix{1&-i\\ i&1}=\pmatrix{1\\ i}\pmatrix{1&-i}
$$
is singular.

The author of your book has probably implicitly assumed that the underlying field is real. First, observe that when $A$ is a skew-symmetric matrix over a field of characteristic $\ne2$, we must have $X^TAX=0$ for every vector $X$, because
\begin{align*}
X^TAX
&=(X^TAX)^T\quad\text{(as $X^TAX$ is a $1\times1$ matrix)}\\
&=X^TA^TX^T\\
&=-X^TAX^T.\\
\end{align*}
(We actually also have $X^TAX=0$ in a field of characteristic $2$, if the definition of skew-symmetric matrix requires that the matrix to have a zero diagonal.)

In particular, $X^TAX=0$ when the field is $\mathbb R$. Now, if $(I-A)X=0$, then $X=AX$. In turn, $\sum_ix_i^2=X^TX=X^TAX=0$. Since all $x_i$s are real numbers, each of them must be zero. Hence $X$ is necessarily zero and $I-A$ is nonsingular.